# Adding Series with Last Row of Data

Tags: vba, charts, series

I am trying to create a macro which automatically adds a series into a chart each time the user enters new data (I will be incorporating this into another macro). I would like the Series values to reference the last row of data in another sheet. I have a working macro which references a fixed cell in another sheet, but not quite sure how to incorporate the Cells(Lr, "B") for another sheet.

I imagine it should be a quick fix, but seem to can't get to it.

I have been able to get it referencing the last row in the same Sheet, but not the last row in another sheet.

```
Sub addSrs()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("User Interface").Select
Dim Lr As Integer
Lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column A

Worksheets("User Interface").ChartObjects(1).Activate

With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = ActiveSheet.Cells(Lr, "A")
    .Values = ActiveSheet.Cells(Lr, "B")
    .XValues = ActiveSheet.Cells(Lr, "C")
End With
```

End Sub

What I have so far:

```
Sub addSrs1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'*******Commented out as does not have use yet...*******
'Sheets("Location Coordinates").Select
'Dim Lr As Integer
'Lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'*******Commented out as does not have use yet...*******

Sheets("User Interface").Select

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 11").Activate
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "='Location Coordinates'!$B$21"
        .Values = "='Location Coordinates'!$K$21"
        .XValues = "='Location Coordinates'!$J$21"
    End With
End Sub
```

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to `Activate` and `Select` your sheets all the time. You can define your last row with a sheet reference, like this : `Lr = Sheets("Location Coordinates").Range("A" & Sheets("Location Coordinates").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` , that way LR is looking for last row in Column A in sheet "Location Coordinates".  As for the second part of your post, change to `.Name = "='Location Coordinates'!$B$" & LR`

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I am still learning with VBA, so thanks for quick tip.